# API Key not valid error when trying to access Google cloud vision api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to test out the vision API and have uploaded some images to Google cloud storage and have created a browser app that requests the cloud api to process them.

I have a client_id file that I downloaded from the Google developers console. This has a client_id value that I am using as my api key.

I make a request to

`https://content-vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json&key=414712345643-cln7htsuv78jr9i64v8v7g6cnhm3ccff.apps.googleusercontent.com`

(api key altered)

and post the request:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "gcsImageUri": "https:\/\/console.cloud.google.com\/m\/cloudstorage\/b\/estoril_test\/o\/AI4C3160.JPG"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/414754136843/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have authorized that api key for the cloud vision api so what am I doing wrong? I did try the curl example in the demo but I keep getting

`Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`

I tried adding double quotes as some research suggested I should but still no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the "API key not valid" issue, it appears that you are using a Server key, but you need to use a browser key. The [Vision API Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/getting-started#setting_up_an_api_key) page has detailed screenshots, as well as a curl example.

The second issue you are likely to encounter is that the `gcsImageUri` is the incorrect format. According to the [Vision API reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#ImageSource) the image URI must be in the form "gs://bucket_name/object_name", so in your case: something like: "gs://storil_test/AI4C3160.JPG"

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It did help but I still have issues.
If I use a browser key then I cannot use it for authenticating a user using OAuth and if I cannot do that I can't access the images in cloud storage as you need an authenticated user to do that. (even though the images are shared publicly)
A browser key only seems to work for uploading images with the request.

Comment: My permissions for my cloud bucket weren't open to all actually. I updated it and I'm getting a different error now!
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is resolved.

After generating credentials, Click on 'Create Credentials' Drop down and choose - 'API Key'; the generated API Key will be used..

Answer (score 6):

Another problem that can be encountered with a KEY not working is that a particular service has not been added to the project you are trying to work with.  That will give this same response.

Comment: This was it for me, pretty non obvious when first starting out that you have to enable each service you want to use the key for

Answer (score 3):

key=414712345643-cln7htsuv78jr9i64v8v7g6cnhm3ccff.apps.googleusercontent.com

This is "ID client Oauth" key.

```
sAjnhsejklfynGiuhYGBYUGDYGziodzdCfhAO7qPY
```

This is an exemple of valid API KEY

To create API KEY follow this link : 
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en